# User Authorization -- New use?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007

I have an app (happens to be in Access 2007) where I've implemented a classic user authorization structure:
Users->Roles->Object Classes->Objects

So, every user is enrolled as one or more role, which maps to one or more Object Classes, which maps to one or more objects in a classic many-to-many relationship. Objects are usually user forms, but include "F11", for example, the ability to open the Access Navigation pane.

To use the structure, I created a query (actually, a SQL Server 'View', since the back end is SQL Server...) that "flattens" it, and essentially allows calling a single "Authorize(User,Object)" function that returns whether or not a given user is authorize for a given object...no muss, no fuss.

Now, I was just asked to set up a structure where users may be authorized as "Initiators", "Approvers", "Administrators", or any combination for a given vendor's timesheets. I thought I'd try to use my standard authorization structure for this new requirement, but I'm a little stumped about how to best structure it.

Does this strike an immediate chord with anyone? I don't have to expose the structure to the user, I'll just make a form that does the work behind the scenes. What do you think? Too complicated? Too Simple?

Comment: Could Authorize(User,Object) return level (admin, init etc), rather than true or false?

Comment: I like where you're going. I've been there already...lol. Authorize actually takes three arguments...(User, ObjectType, Object). Object Type is a column in the Object table. I had sort of deprecated Object Type as redundant, but it could be used here. My actual quandry is how to avoid having lots of redundant Roles and Object Class entries.

Comment: `Authorize(User,Object)` uses user to find roles, and Object to define which roles have access, and returns true/false accordingly.